# POST Array from checkbox via Jquery AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I want to send array from checkbox via Jquery AJAX, but the response is not right.

here the html :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="krs_id_kelas" name="krs_id_kelas[]" value="0ec81bdf-1fc6-447d-ab65-bc67a857d99c">
<input type="checkbox" id="krs_id_kelas" name="krs_id_kelas[]" value="173867c3-5721-4aa2-9344-f5ad9fd05537">
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
$('#form_krs_kolektif').submit(function (event) {

     var formData = {
            'krs_id_prodi': $('#krs_id_prodi').val(), //this part is fine
            'periode': $('#periode_krs option:selected').val(), //this part is fine
            'krs_id_regis_mhs': $('#krs_id_regis_mhs').val(), //this part is fine
            'id_kelas[]': $('#krs_id_kelas:checked').serialize() // only this part has a problem
        };
     $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?=base_url()?>akademik/proses_krs_kolektif/',
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json',
            encode: true
        })

    event.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

When I `print_r` the POST result from php part, the response from console is like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => krs_id_kelas%5B%5D=0ec81bdf-1fc6-447d-ab65-bc67a857d99c&krs_id_kelas%5B%5D=173867c3-5721-4aa2-9344-f5ad9fd05537
)
```

What I want is array like this, how can I fix it ?

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0ec81bdf-1fc6-447d-ab65-bc67a857d99c
    [1] => 173867c3-5721-4aa2-9344-f5ad9fd05537
)
```

Comment: first of all dont keep same id for both, change and check

Comment: I have a lot of checkbox and has a random data. I can't change all of them one by one. The only way is to send as array if the checkbox is checked

Comment: then give a dynamic id, as same id shouldnt exist in the same page

Comment: I just found the answer , I just need to parse_str the post result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML should be, instead of ID you must use class:

```
 <input type="checkbox" class="krs_id_kelas" name="krs_id_kelas[]" value="0ec81bdf-1fc6-447d-ab65-bc67a857d99c">
 <input type="checkbox" class="krs_id_kelas" name="krs_id_kelas[]" value="173867c3-5721-4aa2-9344-f5ad9fd05537">
```

try this script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
 $('#form_krs_kolektif').submit(function (event) {
 var chekedValue = [];
 $('.krs_id_kelas:checked').each(function(){
   chekedValue .push($(this).val());
 })
 var formData = {
        'krs_id_prodi': $('#krs_id_prodi').val(), //this part is fine
        'periode': $('#periode_krs option:selected').val(), //this part is fine
        'krs_id_regis_mhs': $('#krs_id_regis_mhs').val(), //this part is fine
        'id_kelas': chekedValue // only this part has a problem
    };
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?=base_url()?>akademik/proses_krs_kolektif/',
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        encode: true
    })

event.preventDefault();
});

});
```

and print `$_POST` you will get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

try this One
change from

```
var formData = {
    'krs_id_prodi': $('#krs_id_prodi').val(), //this part is fine
    'periode': $('#periode_krs option:selected').val(), //this part is fine
    'krs_id_regis_mhs': $('#krs_id_regis_mhs').val(), //this part is fine
    'id_kelas[]': $('#krs_id_kelas:checked').serialize() // only this part has a problem
};
```

to

```
var formData = $('#form_krs_kolektif').serialize();
```